# Stored procedure for an insert AFTER an update has occurred

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to design a friend's list, similar to other social media sites. I have created 3 tables for this.

Designing the database, if person1 sends a request to person2, their status becomes 0 (pending). Once person2 accepts, the status gets updated to 1 (accepted) and person1 becomes friends with person2. ie. the database will have person1 -> person2 and another entry of person2 -> person1

After the status update, I want to write a stored procedure to automatically insert another row into the friends' request table for person2 to become friends with person1 and with a status of 1.

Desired outcome: after personId2 accepts request, I want the status to get updated to 1 AND for it to create another row as personId2 is friends personId1

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[person_connections_update]
    @PersonId INT,
    @FriendId INT,
    @Status INT
AS
    /*
    DECLARE
        @_personId INT = 1,
        @_friendId INT = 2,
        @_status INT = 0

    EXEC person_connections_update
        @_personId,
        @_friendId,
        @_status
    */
BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        UPDATE person_connections
        SET PersonId = @PersonId,
            FriendId = @FriendId,
            Status = @Status
        WHERE
            PersonId = @PersonId AND FriendId = @FriendId

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        IF (@Status = 1)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO person_connections
            SET --what is the correct syntax here to insert the entry of user 2 being friends with user 1? i basically need to swap the values when the new entry is generated.
                PersonId = @FriendId,
                FriendId = @PersonId,
                Status = 1
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
    END CATCH
END
```

This is what I have for the update so far. this is only updating the status to 1 but I cannot figure out how to create the other entry when the status is changed to 1.

Comment: Could the resulting network of "Friends" be a separate entity? Perhaps termed a "Relationship", identified by its own ID value, and having its own attributes such as "Name" and "Primary Friend"?